# Metro application - Top bar menu

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, appbar

I am developping a metro app in C# on Windows 8. I've added a top bar and I would like to display a menu when the user click a button on it.

For example when you click the tools button in the Internet Explorer App a menu shows up. How to do that ? Which control is used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Popup. You can check the Silverlight Toolkit for ContextMenu example.

Comment: Thanks, I did it with a PopupMenu - example here : [Context menu sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Context-menu-sample-40840351)